# Which replication algorithm is used in Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

Replication algorithms are generally of three types: single-leader, multi-leader and leaderless replication. Which of these is used in Hadoop HDFS? I know that the data never flows through the name node but then should it be leaderless replication with quorum reads and writes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop reads and replicates files based on rack locality, but there is no "single/multi leader". All replicas are equal.

Enabling Erasure Coding might affect that somewhat

Comment: So, what I'm trying to understand is whether the write requests first go to the namenode and then forwarded to the data nodes or the clients directly communicate with the datanodes? @cricket_007

Comment: Got the answer for this in hadoop documentation: `The NameNode is the arbitrator and repository for all HDFS metadata. The system is designed in such a way that user data never flows through the NameNode.`

Comment: Yes, writes and reads go to the datanode directly. The file information (the name and ownership) do go through the namenode, though... But that doesn't really say anything about replication